# Where do I find the authentic information about Ganesha Yantra?

Tags: ganesha, tantra, yantra

I wish to learn about Ganesha Yantra but unable to find any details other than Ucchishta Ganapati Yantra.  What is the authentic Tantra text that discusses Ganesha Yantra and its worship particualrly that which is based on Ganapati Upanishad (Ganapati Atharvashirsha)?

Ganesha Yantra Pictures:

**Yantra 1**
[image: Ganesh Yantra 1]

**Yantra 2**

[image: Ganesh Yantra 2]

Comment: In the Tantras you will find not in the Upanishads.

Answer (score 1):

You can find detailed pooja process and yantra pooja of Sri Ganesha in texts like mantra mahodadhi.

You can check the second chapter starting from page 48.

[**Mantra mahodadhi**](https://archive.org/details/MantraMahodadhiShukadevaChaturvedi)

It also has nyasa and other necessary details for the pooja. Nevertheless, one should be initiated before taking up these poojas and upasanas.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I really appreciate your help, I couldn't find any credible source to study even after asking so many people.  You were of great help.  Thanks again!